# Linux: executable cannot find shared library

Tags: linux, gcc

I have compiled `casablanca` and have put `-l:/~/path/to/lib/libcasablanca.so` in my `CMakeList.txt`. I have build my application and I have got no errors. But when I run the executable it says:

```
./myproj: error while loading shared libraries: libcasablanca.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have done it on another computer and it seems to work fine.

Does anyone know what is the problem? How to fix this?

I have no administrator access to this machine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is very simple: your library is not in the default system path from them the shared libraries are imported. During the compilation, the compile scripts solved these problems. In runtime, you have the `LD_PRELOAD` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables.

For example: an `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/darkside/wunderprog/lib` will extend the directoried searched for your libraries with the named directory. If there is your `libcasablanca.so`, you will get what you want.

Normally I use a `/home/<myusername>/lib` directory in my useronly accounts and set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` from `.profile`.

Comment: If I do `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/~/path/to/lib`, does it removes the values existent in the variable? Or there is nothing in it?

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon Yes, but normally it is empty (the system sharedlib search path isn't there). If you have some important there, you can give him a colon-separated path list, just as we can see in `$PATH`: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/darkmoon/lib:/home/darkmoon/some_another/lib` ...or just so.